# Is possible to put an image instead of a button, and make it clickable?

Tags: image, qt, python-3.x, click, pyside

Is possible to put an Image into a GUI Application and make it clickable?

I used to make a button like this:

```
img = QPixmap(15, 15)
img.fill(Qt.grey)
button = QPushButton(QIcon(img))
button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
```

[Link http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/834/kaqc.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/834/kaqc.png)

But I'd prefer to use an image, instead of having a button with an icon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple demo script that shows how to make a grid of clickable labels:

```
from random import shuffle
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class ClickableLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, width, height, color):
        super(ClickableLabel, self).__init__()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(width, height)
        pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(color))
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setObjectName(color)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit(self.objectName())

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        colors = 'red green blue orange purple yellow'.split()
        for row in range(len(colors)):
            shuffle(colors)
            for column, color in enumerate(colors):
                label = ClickableLabel(25, 25, color)
                label.clicked.connect(self.handleLabelClicked)
                layout.addWidget(label, row, column)

    def handleLabelClicked(self, name):
        print('"%s" clicked' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is really a good example, but what about, if i want to change color on the clicked label instead print the color's name?

Comment: @CarloBeccarini. Move the pixmap-setting code into a method of `ClickableLabel` (it could take the colour as an argument). You can then use `self.sender()` in the signal-handler to get the label that was clicked, and change the colour accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirement and solved it by subclassing QLabel, as yshurik suggests. The amount of additional code is very limited. Here is a working implementation:

```
class CClickableLabel : public QLabel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   CClickableLabel(QString text, QWidget *parent = 0) : QLabel(text, parent) {}
   ~CClickableLabel() {}

signals:
   void clicked();

protected:
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) { emit clicked(); }
};
```

Create a instance CClickableLabel, use setPixmap() to set the image and listen to the clicked() signal. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fast solution is subclass QLabel, use setPixmap() to put image on and reimplement mouseEvent() to submit signal clicked() on press/release event. As it is python (PyQt/PySide) then it should be just few lines. Usually I use such approach when need some graphics clickable.

Comment: I tried that also, before trying buttons, but probably there's no way to put an image as widget :/

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are style able, and you can put images on them.

Comment: I'm trying to make a maze editor, so i'd prefer to put something that seems like a grid..